# Getting body height inside iframe on IE

Tags: javascript

Inside an iframe i am trying to communicate with the parent document the content height in order to resize the iframe. The communication works perfectly, the problem resides on getting the content height. Even after the DOM is loaded the height given is the default which is 30 px instead the actual heigh which is like 5000px. I only get this problem on IE 8 and IE 9.

I have tried to use the window.onload event but it was not getting called, so I tried to have a loop that gets the content height each second in order to see if it was getting updated, but even after all the DOM is loaded, the problem persists.

I have something like this:

```
checkHeightLoop = setInterval(function(){resizeIframe()}, 1000);

function resizeIframe(){
  parent.postMessage("resizeIframe#" + $('body').outerHeight( true ), "*");
}
```

The loop is stupid but was just to see if I could get a different height even after the DOM is loaded, since the event window.onload is not getting called. Besides the Jquery method to get content height I already tried:

```
var x = window.innerHeight,
    y = window.scrollY,
    z = document.body.clientHeight,
    a = document.body.scrollHeight,
    b = document.body.offsetHeight,
    c = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    d = document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    e = document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your entire code to get a picture, but...

Have you tried utilizing the ["window.onload" javascript event handler](http://roberthahn.ca/articles/2007/02/02/how-to-use-window-onload-the-right-way/). It activates after the DOM.

Ok, after reading more on your issue. Try this code inside your parent document:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function aResize(id)
{
    var nh;
    var nw;
        nh=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        nw=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
        document.getElementById(id).height= (nh) + "px";
        document.getElementById(id).width= (nw) + "px";
}
</script>

<iframe src="yourpage.aspx" width="100%" height="100px" id="if1" frameborder="0" onLoad="aResize('if1');"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my post with the code.

Comment: Thanks, since the parent is in another domain will I be able to do    document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight?